# Adding individual folders to created files

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file which serves as a template file, that needs to generate new files according to a list of names.

How do I save them in individual folders with the same name as the file (person's name).

This is what I have:

```
Sub SaveMasterAs()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rNames As Range, c As Range, r As Range
'Current file's list of names and ids on sheet1.
Set rNames = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown))
'Path and name to master workbook to open for copy, saveas.
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\template_2021.xlsm")
For Each c In rNames
With wb
.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\templates" & c.Value & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End With
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Next c
wb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the named folders exist is so what is the parent folder ? If not, under which folder should they be created ? See [filesystemobject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object)

Comment: Hi! I want the folders to be created inside the 'templates' folder and the files to be created inside each created folder.

Comment: What about mail merge?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to put in your code is:

```
MkDir "C:\yourFolderPath"
```

That would create directory and then you have to save your file into it.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Worksheets to Subfolders

- Use variables to make the code more readable and maintainable.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveMasterAs()
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Current file's list of names and ids on sheet1.
    Dim rNames As Range
    Set rNames = sws.Range("A2", sws.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    ' This is usually the preferred (safer) way:
    'Set rNames = sws.Range("A2", sws.Range("A" & sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    'Path and name to master workbook to open for copy, saveas.
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(swb.Path & "\template_2021.xlsm")
    
    Dim c As Range
    Dim cString As String
    Dim dFolderPath As String
    Dim dFilePath As String
    
    For Each c In rNames.Cells
        cString = CStr(c.Value)
        If Len(cString) > 0 Then ' not a blank cell
            dFolderPath = swb.Path & "\templates\" & cString
            If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir dFolderPath
            End With
            dFilePath = dFolderPath & "\" & cString & ".xlsm"
            dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        End If
    Next c
    
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just in case

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there! Really appreciate your help on this. I get an error after adding your code - Run-time error '1004':
Method 'SaveAs' of object_Workbook' failed and it sends me here to debug : dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: I've edited may answer.

Comment: I get an 'End if without With' =/